# Change the background color of any TD that already has a specific background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change some colors on a table that is generated for a calendar. Certain TD's in the table get a different color than others, this was coded by someone else and is done with inline CSS (meaning there is no class/ID assigned). I don't have access to the code they created to change it and can only try to overwrite the color.

What I am trying to do is use a short script to find any TD element that has the particular color, in this case LightSlateGray, and change it to a different background color.

Below is what I mostly recently tried but I know that I am doing something incorrectly and am hoping someone can point it out to me.

```
var tdColor = $("td"); 
    if(tdColor.css('background-color') === 'LightSlateGray'){
        tdColor.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
```

Comment: Since you state that it's inline CSS, you should be able to select the `<td>` elements by using an attribute selector like: `td[style*="background-color:LightSlateGray"]`. All td elements that have a style attribute that contain the string `background-color:LightSlateGray`. Add a space if needed. Then loop over the elements.

Comment: Wow thank you for the tip, I didn't know about the need of an asterisk, worked like a charm! If you put it as an answer I am happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each element:

```
var tdColor = $("td");
tdColor.each(function() {
    $this = $(this); 
    if($this.css('background-color') === 'LightSlateGray'){
        $this.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
```